# Выбор фреймрейта в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю игру в юнити. Мне нужно в настройках сделать выбор фреймрейта в игре. Как в скрипте сделать, чтобы при нажатии кнопки (не на клавиатуре, а в игре) ФПС принимал определенное значение?
Я искал в интернете и сам пробовал что-то сделать, но у меня не вышло(
Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings-vSyncCount.html

Comment: В добавок к ответу @aepot https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html

Answer (score 0):

Версия с Button

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NazvanieScripta : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool buttonfpsclicked;
    void Start()
    {
        buttonfpsclicked = false;
    }
    public void ClickedOnButton()
    {
        if(buttonfpsclicked == false)
        {
            Application.targetFrameRate = 0; '''тут пишем ФПС который будет при первом нажатии на кнопку, 0 это бесконечно, (будет выдавать сколько максимум может) '''
            buttonfpsclicked = true;
        }
        else
        {
            Application.targetFrameRate = 60; '''тут уже пишем ФПС при втором нажатии '''
        }
    }
}
```

А вот потом бросаем скрипт на кнопку (только не так как просто закинул)
Выходим в редактор, нажимаем на кнопку, и там листаем вниз
Ищем Button и там в конце On Click()
Нажимаем +, забрасываем скрипт на любой объект
И этот объект из анархии перетаскиваем в поле None (Object)
Перенесли? Нажимаем на No Function, и ищем название скрипта, наводим, и там где то будет ClickedOnButton (), нажимаем, и теперь у нас изменяется ФПС, который мы поставили, либо есть второй вариант с InputField(какой введешь - такой ФПС и будет)
Версия с InputField. Нужна кнопка что бы принимать значение

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NazvanieScripta : MonoBehaviour
{
    public InputField nazvanieinputa; '''название можно изменить'''
    public void ClickedOnButton()
    {
        Application.targetFrameRate = nazvanieinputa.text;
    }
}
```

И тем же способом кидаем на кнопку.
Писал где то 20 минут.

Comment: Лучше используй InputField. меньше всяких ресурсов потратится
Из-за этого ФПС может быть на 1 выше, что иногда важно